# Rows as columns from same table joined by unique value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling to build a query - the result should be sourced from two tables:

`values` table:

```
eventid | elementid |   value
-------------------------------
10      |  1        |   1234
11      |  1        |   1234
11      |  2        |   True
```

So the `values` table can have multiple values for the same `elementid`.

`events` table:

```
eventid | eventuid
-------------------
10      |  abcdef
11      |  ghijkg
```

**My goal** is to build a query that displays

```
value1  |   value2  |   eventuid
-----------------------------
True    |  1234     |   abcdef
True    |  5678     |   ghijkg
```

- Column A: the value for `element1`
- Column B: the value for `element2`
- Column C: the eventuid

**but only if the value for `elementid=1` is unique** i.e. there are no `eventid`s with the same value for the same `elementid=1`.

My attempt was to create a view first:

```
create view unique_event as
select distinct e.eventuid, count(v.value)
from events e
join values v on e.eventid = v.eventid
where v.elementid = 1
group by e.eventuid
having count(v.value) = 1;
```

This seems to work to only return the distinct `eventuid`s -
and then read from that view but I'm not able to "pivot" the values:

```
select v.value as value1, e.eventuid
from events e
join value v on v.eventid = e.eventid
where e.eventuid in (select eventuid from unique_event)
and v.elementid in (1, 2)
group by e.eventuid, v.value;
```

Comment: "the value for `element1`" - there is no element1 or element2 in your tables. Please clarify.

Comment: And please clarify the uniqueness criteria. You said "but only if the value for elementid=1 is unique" - the `value` field of both records with id 1 is "1234" so it would not be unique; but then you say "i.e. there are no eventids with the same value for the same elementid=1" - so does that mean the `value` field has to be unique per `eventid` and `elementid` combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already done the more complex part with creating the list of unique events you want to include!

From there it is easy to get the table you want.

```
--note that you do not need "distinct" since you are already grouping by the event ids

create view unique_event as
select  max(e.eventuid::text) as eventuid 
 , v.value
 , max(e.eventid) as e.eventid)
from events e
join values v on e.eventid = v.eventid
where v.elementid = 1
group by v.value
having count(e.eventid) = 1;

select e.eventuid
--since we want only one row for the event, we have to tell it which value we want of the value column
--since max ignores null, this will give us the non-null value
-- but if there is only record for the event, min would work just as well
, max(case when v.elementid = 1 then value end) as value1
, max(case when v.elementid = 2 then value end) as value2
from unique_event e
join values v on e.eventid = v.eventid
group by e.eventuid
having max(case when v.elementid = 2 then value end) = 'True'
```

Comment: What would you recommend adding when I only need to display rows `where elementid=2 and value=True` ? Currently I see every row regardless of that value

Comment: actually I don't think the `view` is returning correctly the `eventuid` where the `value` for `elementid=1` is unique

Comment: Updated the initial view based on your comment and added an example of filtering in the SELECT statement